# Is it possible to change speed during an animation in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

The question, in brief, is: *is it possible (with the tools of matplotlib.animation or other modules for python) to obtain a slow-motion on certain frames of the animation?*

**Some context:**

I have a matplotlib animated plot in which I am varying one variable and showing a contour plot over two other ones. My idea was to slow down the animation while I am near the maximum of the function, so that I can more clearly pinpoint it, while accelerate far from it where there is not much interest.

At the moment, my best idea is to double the frames closest to the maximum, but can someone have a better idea?

Thank you everyone!

---

Code snippet:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np
X = np.linspace(1,10, 100)
Y = np.linspace(1,10, 100)
R = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)
ims = []

for r in R:
    z = func(X, Y, r)
    im = plt.imshow(z)
    ims.append(im)
    if check_r(r):
        ims.append(im)
```

where `func()` is a function that return a `(len(X), len(Y))` array that depends on `r` (for instance `Z[i,j] = X[i]**r * Y[j]**(1-r)` or whatever, while `check_r()` test if `r` is within the range of the values that need to be maximized.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is the best, I think. And I've found another way using matplotlib animation. The idea is that use frames as slow delay, by making same points.

In this example just sin curve is plotted but it will be applied other functions.

([most of code is took from here](https://riptutorial.com/matplotlib/example/23562/save-animation-to-gif))

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import pandas as pd

TWOPI = 2*np.pi
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# making frames "delay"
frames = np.arange(0.0, TWOPI, 0.1)
frames = np.insert(frames, 17, [1.7]*5)
frames = np.insert(frames, 16, [1.6]*5)
frames = np.insert(frames, 15, [1.5]*5)

t = np.arange(0.0, TWOPI, 0.001)
s = np.sin(t)
l = plt.plot(t, s)

ax = plt.axis([0,TWOPI,-1,1])

redDot, = plt.plot([0], [np.sin(0)], 'ro')

def animate(i):
    redDot.set_data(i, np.sin(i))
    return redDot,

myAnimation = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=frames, 
                                      interval=100, blit=True, repeat=True)
```

Comment: Thank you, but I think this is the same solution that i found, except that in this way you are repeating the computations for each __frame__, while in my case the computation is done only once. If the computation is more expensive than a simple `sin` function this could be a problem for your solution!